# Is there a way to query a table with a where clause on a related table but still grab all related content to the original table with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables that are related. Table A and Table B. Table A has a one-to-many relationship with Table B. I want to retrieve all instances of A that has an instance of B related to it with a status of pending.

The query used is shown below, what I'm trying to achieve is to grab all instances of A with an instance of B whose status is `pending`.

```
await A.findAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    include: [
      {
        model: B,
        where: {
          status: 'pending'
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

The code above returns multiple instances of the same instance of A which isn't the expected result. If an instance of A has two instances of B related to it with a status of `pending`, it'll return A twice with just the instance that's pending.

A sample of table B is shown below

```
Table B
id     name     status       a_id
1      sample1  completed    1
2      sample2  pending      1
3      sample3  pending      1
4      sample4  pending      2
5      sample5  completed    3
5      sample6  completed    3
5      sample7  completed    3
```

An example of table A is shown below

```
Table A
id      name
1       typeA
2       typeB
3       typeC
```

If I run the query for with this data, I get an output like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'typeA',
        Bs: [
            { id: 2, name: 'sample2', status: 'pending' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'typeA',
        Bs: [
            { id: 3, name: 'sample3', status: 'pending' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'typeB',
        Bs: [
            { id: 4, name: 'sample4', status: 'pending' }
        ]
    }
]
```

But the expected output should be something like

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'typeA',
        Bs: [
            { id: 1, name: 'sample1', status: 'completed' },
            { id: 2, name: 'sample2', status: 'pending' },
            { id: 3, name: 'sample3', status: 'pending' }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'typeB',
        Bs: [
            { id: 4, name: 'sample4', status: 'pending' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Basically get all instances of B related to A where any of the Bs has a status of `pending`.

Comment: is group by of any help?

Comment: What you're seeing is the way SQL works. If you join to another table, you get one result row for each joined row. You can transform the result structure after the fact, or you could get all the A rows and then get the list of B rows for each; however that's a lot more querying.

Comment: @Ramesh I haven't tried groupBy, can you point me to a link so I can read about it?

Comment: @Pointy Are you saying there's no way I can get the other rows including the joined row that meets the condition specified.?

Comment: Well you *are* getting the rows, right? I mean, there's no information that your current query fails to return, right? Yes, the columns from A are repeated for each B row, but again that's SQL.

Comment: @proton - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html .. I am thinking grouping on A might help.. but i am not sure as I have never tries sequelize

Comment: Lol, I know it's SQL I'm asking if there's a work around because I need all the rows and not only the ones that meet the condition specified. As you can see in the expected output, I'm getting the row with a status of `completed` too.

Comment: Grouping is useful if you want to aggregate the "B" rows. Some databases let you collapse a column from multiple rows to an array with an aggregate function (Postgresql for example); I don't know if Sequelize can do that.

Comment: Wait - if you want the B rows with status "completed" then why do you include the predicate for status being "pending"? *edit* oh I see, you want *all* the B rows where there's at least one "pending"; that's more of a condition on A (in SQL it'd be a `EXISTS ()` clause).

Comment: I need it for analytics purpose, so basically if any A has a B that's pending, I want to retrieve all the B's related to it so I can perform some calculations on it and display to the user.

Comment: @Pointy I think I understand what you're saying a bit. I'm actually not too versed with SQL syntax so I'm going to read about the `EXISTS ()` clause. Or can you help with a sample snippet using the `EXISTS ()` clause

Comment: Yea I'm reading about Sequelize. In raw SQL it's pretty easy; you'd get rid of the "pending" predicate on B, and add an `EXISTS` clause that basically means "there's at least one row of B for this A id that has status 'pending'".