# How can I retrieve the output of an INNER JOIN in an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I have this SQL query

```
 '(SELECT “A”.”id" AS “aId”, “A”.”name”, “A”.”updatedAt" AS “aUpdatedDate”, “B”.”name” AS “b.name”, “B”.”status” AS “b.status”,  FROM “A” INNER JOIN “B” ON “A”.”id" = “B”.”a_id” WHERE EXISTS (SELECT “status” FROM “B” WHERE “B”.”a_id” = “A”.”id" AND “B”.”status" IN (‘pending’, ‘failed’))) OFFSET ? LIMIT ?’;
```

This returns the data needed but the problem is I'd love to get the data in this format. This is the expected output:

```
{
    aid: 1,
    name: 'nameOne',
    aUpdatedDate: '2018-09-10',
    Bs: [
        {
             name: 'b-one',
             status: 'completed'
        },
        {
             name: 'b-two',
             status: 'pending'
        }
    ]
}
```

but instead the output separates each instance of B which in turns duplicates the A's that are returned. The actual output returned is like this

```
{
    aid: 1,
    name: 'nameOne',
    aUpdatedDate: '2018-09-10',
    'b.name': 'b-one',
    'b.status': 'completed'
},
{
    aid: 1,
    name: 'nameOne',
    aUpdatedDate: '2018-09-10',
    'b.name': 'b-two',
    'b.status': 'pending'
},
```

For a bit of context, you can check out the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923159/is-there-a-way-to-query-a-table-with-a-where-clause-on-a-related-table-but-still?noredirect=1#comment94688155_53923159) link which explains why I'm using a `WHERE EXISTS` clause and for a bit of background on the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `raw : true` , either remove it or make it false :

```
sequelize.query('SELECT...', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT , raw : false }).then(results => {
  console.log(results)
})
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: `raw` is set to false already and I still get the same result

Comment: It's too long, let me put it in a pastebin

Comment: @proton , then I think you have to define the associations , read this : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1830

Comment: I have defined a `hasMany` association on Loan. Using some examples in the issue, I refactored the query to this: 

https://pastebin.com/WKamRRgX

All that's left is how to do an Include on a raw query